# How to append an array in parameters after Rails form submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a form with checkboxes that get passed as an array "list_person_ids" on form submit. My models are "Occurance" which has an n:m relationship with "ListPerson" through the Model "Person". "list_person_ids" are saved in Person with the Occurance id and the ListPerson id.

I want to append one or more values to the array before this gets saved. The reason I need to do this is because the user can also add a new value in ListPerson using a textbox with the name "person_name".

```
def create
  @occurance = Occurance.new(occurance_params)
  add_person_id(@occurance)
  ...
  # save
end

def add_person_id(object)
  if params[:person_check] == '1'
    object.list_person_ids.push( ListPerson.find_or_create_by(person: params[:person_name]).id )
  end
end

def occurance_params
  params.require(:occurance).permit(:person_check, :person_name, dim_person_ids: [])
end
```

find_or_create_by is successful, but nothing gets pushed to the array "list_person_ids". There is also no error message. Do I have to give permission somewhere to append this array? Please let me know if some information is missing.

Answer (score 0):

on your model you can do something like below:

```
....

before_create :create_lists

private

def create_lists
  ListPerson.find_or_create_by(list_person_ids: person_name.id)
end
```